# Android EditText background text

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

Is there a way to set the background text of an EditText? for instance, I have a login screen with 2 EditText views, one for username and one for password. I want the text "Username" and "Password" be written inside the EditText, and once the user touches those the text disappears but once user deleted his own entry, text re-appears.

Is there a property for that or should I implement this on my own with events and stuff?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The `hint` property will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 12):

Use [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint) property, or [setHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) method.

Comment: Thanks for including solutions for both XML and .java as well as links to the source. +1